# Android use multiple manifest files

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a project which include libraries. Only inside the library i access the external storage. Now i have 2 manifest files, one inside the main project and one inside the library. Which one should be used for write the permission to access the file system? Is it better to always use only the main project manifest file?

Comment: without doubt your main project manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to define permission in main project. no need to define permission in library project.